# Symfony 6 is security.enable_authenticator_manager a redundant setting?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I have an authenticator class which extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator and I declared it with the security.firewalls.main.custom_authenticator setting.

However, I omitted to set the security.enable_authenticator_manager setting - but everything works just as expected with no extra deprecations etc. I guess that when enable_authenticator_manager is not set it defaults to false, but the authenticator class is used anyway. What's the purpose of this setting?

Comment: It was used in Symfony 5 to select between the older Guard based authentication and the newer Http authentication.  Since the Guard software is now completely removed in Symfony 6 then the setting is no longer needed.  I suppose eventually it will be removed.

Comment: It is deprecated now in 6.2. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/47890

Answer (score 7):

Symfony introduced a new [authentication manager](https://symfony.com/doc/5.1/security/experimental_authenticators.html) in 5.1. Setting `security.enable_authenticator_manager` allowed you to opt into it.

From 6.0 the new authentication manager was mandatory, and from 6.2 this setting was [deprecated altogether](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/47890).

To summarise, do not set this from Symfony 6.2 onwards.